Why did Jesus choose to pray after they tried making him king?
In John 6:15 it says, "Therefore when Jesus perceived that they were about to come and take Him by force to make Him king, He departed again to the mountain by Himself alone."
We see in the parallel account of Mark 6:46 that it says, "And when He had sent them away, He departed to the mountain to pray."
Is there any indication within the text as to why Jesus' chooses to pray after they tried making him king?

If there are no explicit clues in the text, it might be legitimate to infer that the new situation give him an urgent need for advice and guidance.

The four accounts of this part of the incident are as follows:

Matthew 14:23 - After He had sent them away, He went up on the mountain by Himself to pray. When evening came, He was there alone
Mark 6:46 - After bidding them farewell, He went up on the mountain to pray.
Luke: --
John 6:15 - Then Jesus, realizing that they were about to come and make Him king by force, withdrew again to a mountain by Himself.

Luke does not even record Jesus going up the mountain.  However, the point remains that Jesus was in the habit of praying often and extensively, ie, for extended periods -

Mark 1;35 - Early in the morning, while it was still dark, Jesus got up and slipped out to a solitary place to pray.
Luke 5:16 - Yet He frequently withdrew to the wilderness to pray.
Luke 6:12 - In those days Jesus went out to the mountain to pray, and He spent the night in prayer to God.
Luke 9:28 - And it came to pass, about eight days after these sayings, and having taken Peter and John and James, He went up on the mountain to pray.

I notice that in almost all these cases, the pattern of Jesus was to pray either:

before a significant decision/event such the Gethsemane experience
after an exhausting day of teaching & preaching

Thus, it appears that Jesus would have gone to mountain to pray whether the crown had wanted to make Jesus king by force or not.  However, the threatened coronation made dismissing the crowd more urgent and thus, He told the disciples to get into a boat and go the other side of the lake.
Lastly, Jesus (whatever else He was) was fully human and a large crown wanting to crown Him king would have been, for most humans, a great temptation.  Jesus immediately rejected such entreaties and dismissed all people to re-establish His intimate connection with the Father and maintain his "lazer-focus" on the real objective of His spiritual mission.
Indeed, Jesus' mission was a spiritual mission and not a temporal one.  That is, Jesus was to be a spiritual king of the heavenly kingdom and not an earthly king and any suggestion of an earthly coronation had to be immediately quashed!
Thus, Jesus needed to be alone in prayer with the Father.

Dottard +1. A beautiful answer. Positively, often you save my time by giving the same answer I could have given! I have left many posts unanswered here because you have already answered them and I have nothing new to add.

Sometimes I add some information enthusiastically here thinking them to be new, only to find out later that you have already mentioned them here a couple of years before!

@NepheshRoi - many thanks for your kind and generous remarks.

The text in John's Gospel account does give a clue, but only in translations that correctly translate the Greek word semeion as 'sign', and not 'miracle'.

"The men, then, having seen the sign that Jesus did, said, 'This is
truly the Prophet, who is coming to the world'. Jesus, therefore,
having known that they are about to come, and to take him by force
that they may make him king, retired again to the mountain himself alone."
John 6:14-14 YLT

When Jesus performed miracles, he was not inclined to then disappear away from the scene of his miracles. Yet when he performed a sign, that was to point to something of great importance. We get our English word 'semaphore' from the Greek semeion. Different flags with different symbols, raised or lowered in different combinations, tell the person observing something important - they give out a message. The person waving the flags is not to be observed. He is not the message!
So with this sign Jesus performed. He was pointing to the Kingdom of God and God's provision for those to be called into it. But the huge crowd saw the miraculous provision of food, which blinded them to the message they ought to have grasped - about the Kingdom of God. They only saw Jesus, and the way this man could provide a free lunch for thousands. "What if he became our king over the nation of Israel?" they immediately wondered.
So blind were they to the way Jesus had taught that the Kingdom of God was spiritual, not a literal rule of men on Earth, they wanted to grab Jesus and make him their earthly king. He (reading minds and hearts) knew what would happen if he did not escape immediately, and, having hidden from them, no doubt got straight to prayer. That had been a close call.
We do not know what he prayed about, but throughout his ministry he repeated the phrase that "my time has not yet come". That huge crowd of men could not grab him, nor could anyone force Jesus to conform to unspiritual aspirations. The next scene is at night, when he miraculously walks on the turbulent water to assure the disciples in the boat that he was with them, no matter how dark and dangerous the situation seemed. As this book puts it:

"The Spirit of life in Christ Jesus was unaffected by the law that
would have sunk all other men, including Israel, down into the depths.
He was unique, transcendent, superior to the laws of gravity or
buoyancy, time and space. He was over all. Then who was Moses?
The multitude knew that besides their own shipping, there was only one
boat available to the disciples. They were also aware that the
disciples had departed without Jesus. When the multitude could find no
trace of him, he being alone on the mount, they crossed the sea the
next day, thence to go to Capernaum, seeking for Jesus, John 6:22-24.
Greatly puzzled when they found him, they said, 'Rabbi, when camest
thou hither?' The answer was, By walking over two and up to three
miles upon the turbulent sea, reaching the boat rowed by the
disciples, and, being received by them, calming their fears,
immediately coming to the land whither they went.
He ignored the question, having no intention of giving an answer to
satisfy their curiosity, or further agitate their excitement.
Instead he replied, 'Ye seek me, not because ye saw the signs [semeia]
but because ye did eat of the loaves, and were filled.' These words of
Jesus naturally lead to and open in context the discourse on 'the day
following' verse 22, the sign of the feeding of the five thousand with
five barley loaves and two small fishes, succeeded by that of which
none but the disciples were aware, namely, Jesus walking on the
water." John chapters 1 to 12: the first six signs, John Metcalfe,
pages 274-276
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

That last sentence makes me think that Jesus needed to escape the turmoil to seek the Father in prayer to know his will for what to do next, in order that that misunderstood sign be followed with another sign. Given the inability of merely materially-minded men to understand that previous sign, the next one was to underscore it, for the benefit of the disciples who were called into the Kingdom of God. Hence his walking on the water at night, in broiling waves, to immediately land them all on the shore. His prayer on the mountain no doubt directed him as to what to do next, according to the Father's will.

This is a point at which John is synoptic with Mark (at least to the tune of three words)
He's to be made king in John but doesn't pray, and he prays in Mark but isn't to be made king.
It might be nice to find some agreement and slightly widen the overlap, but John might just be tweaking the other version.
Placing the two lines side-by-side:-

(Mark 6:45-46) - - ἕως αὐτὸς ἀπολύει τὸν ὄχλον. καὶ ἀποταξάμενος αὐτοῖς
ἀπῆλθεν εἰς τὸ ὄρος προσεύξασθαι.
(John 6:15) - - Ἰησοῦς οὖν γνοὺς ὅτι μέλλουσιν ἔρχεσθαι καὶ ἁρπάζειν
αὐτὸν ἵνα ποιήσωσιν βασιλέα, ἀνεχώρησεν πάλιν εἰς τὸ ὄρος αὐτὸς
μόνος.

The stronger the overlap is felt to be between the two descriptions, the more ἀνεχώρησεν looks like a rephrasing of ἀπῆλθεν (as if doing a thesaurus-job on it), and εἰς τὸ ὄρος a direct lift.

Idiom?
Mark's προσεύξασθαι is an infinitive with verb-of-motion expressing intent - which is idiomatic (https://archive.org/details/completegreekgra00donauoft/page/598/mode/2up) but John mightn't have liked it if he's Greek-as-a-Foreign-Language or otherwise wants a preposition equivalent to ל or ἵνα.
(But he does have at least one example of one of these at John 21:3 Ὑπάγω ἁλιεύειν, so it's probably not this)

Sound-effects?
εἰς τὸ ὄρος αὐτὸς μόνος is pretty ugly - due to the ος on ὄρος obfuscating the syntax when it's picked up by the ὸς on αὐτὸς. As prose metre, it's pointed (which still comes across it reading aloud) but the idea isn't climactic or complex to need that sort of emphasis or clarification. So it's probably not for reasons of poetry, rhythm, or sound-effect.

Thematic Interest?
Mark is usually said to place more emphasis on the secrecy of Jesus' mission, but that doesn't mean John particularly uses the mention of βασιλέα at John 6:15 to launch a detailed treatment of the 'Conquering Messiah' trope. It's only picked up again when Pilate questions him in John 18.
But that can go both ways - John might be dropping in ποιήσωσιν βασιλέα at an earlier point in the narrative so that Pilate's motives and interest are clearer in the climax. εἰς τὸ ὄρος αὐτὸς μόνος then is the more important idea than the προσεύξασθαι, because it emphasises the withdrawal from the temptation of earthly power. John doesn't have the temptation by Satan like the synoptic gospels (only Luke and Matthew develop the point about kingship).
Jesus could still have been described praying, it's not an either-or.
Except it is: then as now good editing (when John is the sequel of a sequel) removes anything that isn't contributing to theme.
John's usage of prayer is somewhat structural compared to the other apostles, and reserved for key plot-points:- (i) the raising of Lazarus, (ii) the garden of Gethsemane, (iii) the high priestly prayer. Mentioning minor prayers that didn't produce reader-obvious and impactful changes to the course of the narrative might be something John wants to limit in case it detracts from prayers as turning-points.

"Bad" reasons?
A good reason finds more beauty in the work, but consider:-
If John's gospel is being recited at dinner-parties by a celebrity promoter with a lisp they might not want an ξ so close to a σθ in προσεύξασθαι.
That sort of thing isn't bad because it's inferential, it's bad because it doesn't reveal any beauty for us, as the locus of composition.

Historic reasons
These don't really apply to a question like this, but unless they find Jesus' lunchbox in the right sediment strata halfway up the side of the mountain, or his jet-skis, or the charred remains of his red-haired stepchild, we can't begin to guess what his internal state of mind or motives were.
All that can be said is Mark's Jesus prays +1 times and John's Jesus goes off on his own +1 times - if there's beauty to be found it's in the ways the authors establish him as a character.
There might be perceived a sufficient gestalt in the thematic interest, but it's pretty faint: a single word isn't enough to prove something like that. But that's all we ever have with writing: single words in a row, most of which (in a record-setting international bestseller) have been carefully and craftily selected.

The way the OP frames the question does leave one perplexing puzzle: which is why Jesus chooses i.e. in and of himself, as distinct from the text whose character he is. This raises the contention that Jesus not only doesn't choose in either gospel, in John's gospel he doesn't pray.
To wheel out a theological perspective at the end of a literary approach: this comes with his being incarnate in the same fictional flesh as us (per Ephesians 2:10). In Jesus the ποίημα θεοῦ is perfect: where we are indistinct and unfinished and 'wandering' about in the composition, Jesus is what he says himself to be. What he is silent about never existed for questions to arise about it.

The sequence is that He went to pray solitarily after the crowd decided to make Him king; now, the reason should be searched in the motivation of people for desiring and intending to enthrone Him as the messianic king of Jews.
Unfortunately, this motivation was earthly and not heavenly: the crowd was satiated by bread in desert and they thought: "How great! This man will never fail us in giving us bread, for He gave it to us even in the desert! So, all our economic problems will be solved with him!"
But correct reaction should have been: "We followed Him to listen to His words about what it is to be a good and God-pleasing man; what is divine destination for humans; how to love God and each other as God wants us to? We got hungry, but because we searched for those spiritual things, the heavenly bread, we did not luck the earthly consolation by earthly bread as well, which provides us a teaching example that if we search and go after spiritual things, the earthly will be given to us also!"
I guess, the Lord went to pray in order that the Jews He addressed be kind of physically disentangled from their wrongheaded expectations from Him; to pray for them to become less stiff-necked and more receptive to His spiritual teachings and think about heavenly bread and heavenly kingdom primarily, and not about the earthly bread and earthly things.
